# How does this code works in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learning assembly on x86 and came across a code which actully zeroing the bss section where all unintialised variable are stored

```
    ;Zero the bss
     movw    $__bss_start, %di
     movw    $_end+3, %cx
     xorl    %eax, %eax
     subw    %di, %cx
     shrw    $2, %cx
     rep; stosl
```

But not sure how this piece of code works .Could anybody let me know how things are going on here,first instruction would be storing the address of bss segment to di register but whats purpose of last three instruction??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this;

```lisp
 ;Zero the bss
 movw    $__bss_start, %di  ; Get start of BSS in %di register
 movw    $_end+3, %cx       ; Get end of BSS in %cx register
 xorl    %eax, %eax         ; Clear %eax 
 subw    %di, %cx           ; Calculate size of BSS (%cx-%di) to %cx
 shrw    $2, %cx            ; Divide %cx by 4
 rep stosl                  ; Repeat %cx times, store %eax (4 bytes of 0) at 
                            ; address %di and increase %di by 4.
```

On the `rep stosl`;

- [`rep`](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/readings/i386/REP.htm) is a repeat prefix that will repeat the following instruction (out of a limited set) %cx times.
- [`stosl`](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/readings/i386/STOS.htm) stores the value of %eax at the address pointed to by %(e)di, and increases %e(di) by the size of %eax.

As an example, `rep stosl` with %eax set to 0, %edi set to 0x4000 and %cx set to 4, will set the memory from  0x4000 to %0x4010 to zero.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim ,could you please be more specific about last 2 instruction and hwo actully bss is zeroing??

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar Updated with a little more info.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that %e(di) is only incremented if the DF flag is 0 - it's decremented if the DF flag is 1. You should really have a `CLD` or `STD` instruction to set the direction. Also worth mentioning that the destination segment for a `STOS` instruction is in es, which may be relevant if you are working with a segmented memory model.

Answer (score 1):

The magic is `rep; stosl`: `stosl` stores the 4 bytes in `eax` to the memory pointed to by `edi` and increments `edi` by 4. The `rep` prefix causes this instruction to be repeated until the counter in `ecx` reaches zero, and each time `ecx` is decremented by one.

So all we need to do is put the address of the .bss segment into `edi` (first instruction), and the number of 4-byte words into `ecx`. This is just `(bss_start - bss_end) >> 2`, which is computed by the remaining instructions.

Comment: @Kerek just one doubt why ,its like $_end+3 ,bss should be marked as _end only .

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: Rounding to pad the section size *up* to the nearest multiple of four.

Comment: Got your point @Kerrek ,Suppose end address is 41 and adding 3 to it make sure that it is multiple of four ,Is it what you meant in above lines